# Eliminar caracter de mi variable PHP

Tags: php, variables

Tengo un codigo PHP el cual envio la variable con un punto.
Yo le mando el valor por http://localhost/?pedido=2023&importe=100.25

 Mi codigo:

```html
<?php
$v1 = $_GET['importe'];
$v2 = $_GET['pedido'];

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
require('config.php');



$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'eur',
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => 'ID del pedido',
        "description"=>"$v2",
      ],
      "unit_amount" => "$v1",
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => 'http://localhost/recibido.php',
  'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/cancelado.php',
]);

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pagina de pagos</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">


  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="contenedor">
    <h2>ID del pedido: <?php echo $v2?></h2>
    <h2>Total pedido: <?php echo $v1?></h2>
    <button id="checkout-button">Pagar</button>
    <script>
      var stripe = Stripe("<?php echo $publishableKey?>");
      const btn = document.getElementById("checkout-button")
      btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: "<?php echo $session->id; ?>"
        });
      });
    </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

El problema esta que mi codigo falla cuando le envio el . en $importe

Ejemplo: 100.25 y necesito eliminar ese punto.

Necesito poder hacer que se elimine el . para que funcione correctamente el codigo.

Tal vez creando una variable y remplazando?

Alguna idea?

Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 3):

prueba usando la función `str_replace()` de `PHP`

```php
$str = '100.00';
echo $str; //output: 100.00
$strSinPunto = str_replace('.', '', $str);
echo $strSinPunto; //output 10000
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, te amo Kevin.

Comment: de nada, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptado para que a mas persona les sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que ver una cosa, 100.25 nunca será igual a 10025. A futuro tendrás problemas.

Repliqué tu código

```
<?php

    $v1 = $_GET['importe'];
    $v2 = $_GET['pedido'];

    $session = [
      'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
      'line_items' => [[
        'price_data' => [
          'currency' => 'eur',
          'product_data' => [
            'name' => 'ID del pedido',
            "description"=>"$v2",
          ],
          "unit_amount" => "$v1",
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
      ]],
      'mode' => 'payment',
      'success_url' => 'http://localhost/recibido.php',
      'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/cancelado.php',
    ];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contenedor">
    <h2>ID del pedido: <?php echo $v2?></h2>
    <h2>Total pedido: <?php echo $v1?></h2>
    <button id="checkout-button">Pagar</button>
    <script>
      var stripe = Stripe("<?php echo $publishableKey?>");
      const btn = document.getElementById("checkout-button")
      btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: "<?php echo $session->id; ?>"
        });
      });
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi resultado

[image: Resultado]

Que error te daba antes??